# How can I open GUI Android SDK Manager? (For Linux)

Tags: android, linux

Previously we could open `Android SDK Manager` like this:
`$ cd sdk_path/tools/
 $ ./android sdk`
 
and result: [image]
But when I ran same commands, I get this message:
`The android command is no longer available.
For manual SDK and AVD management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager`

How can I open GUI Android SDK Manager?

Comment: That SDK Manager was discontinued, AFAIK. You can use [the command-line `sdkmanager` tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html) or use the one that is part of Android Studio.

Comment: You're not the only one with this issue, and some developers took it into their own hands to make a GUI SDK manager! If you're using a Windows system, this answer may be of help (I see you're not on a Windows system, but for any passerbys that are): https://stackoverflow.com/a/44244605/3126316

Answer (score 1):

OS: Xubuntu x64

I have the same problem on linux. Download the lates Android SDK 26.0.1, but can't load GUI sdk manager.

Solution:
I found previous version here: https://www.techspot.com/downloads/5425-android-sdk.html
Unpack and run from the console /tools/android
And then GUI sdk manager run's

Answer (score 0):

Go to `sdkfolder/tools`. There is a file named just `android`

In a terminal run the command:

```sh
./android
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear about it, that it is now called `sdkmanager`.